# Is there a way to give instance specific value to a variable in verilog apart from parameter/defparam and `define approaches?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

```
module top;
    m m1();
    m m2();
endmodule

module m;
    reg r;
    initial begin
        $display("%b", r);
    end
endmodule
```

I want different values for `top.m1.r` and `top.m2.r` . We can achieve this by using a parameter and then adding defparams on it. But Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `` `define ``s to do this, and `defparam` is not recommended. You can do

```
module top;
    m #(0) m1();
    m #(1) m2();
endmodule

module m #(bit P);
    reg r = P;
    initial begin
        $display("%b", r);
    end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using a parameter as @[dave_59](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53535044/5451783) described is the preferred method. However, it is also possible to use assignment statements with hierarchical references at runtime:

```
module top;
    m m1();
    m m2();

    initial
      begin
        m1.r = 0;
        m2.r = 1;
      end
endmodule

module m;
    reg r;
    initial begin
        #0;
        $display("%b", r);
    end
endmodule
```

There is a race condition because the initialization and the print statements both occur at time 0 due to the `initial` statements. That's why I had to sneak in the `#0` delay before printing.